# Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component - When adding Loader component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm working a Nextjs - Typescript project. I'am trying to add a Loader component. while page is loading loader component is true. otherwise false.

This is my code:

LoderContext.ts

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import { NextPage } from "next";
type State = { loading: boolean };
type Action = { type: "startLoading" } | { type: "endLoading" };
type Dispatch = (action: Action) => void;

export const LoadingContext =
  React.createContext<{ state: State; dispatch: Dispatch } | undefined>(
    undefined
  );

const initialState = {
  loading: true,
};

const { Provider } = LoadingContext;

const reducer = (state: State, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "startLoading":
      return {
        loading: true,
      };
    case "endLoading":
      return {
        loading: false,
      };
    default:
      throw state;
  }
};

const LoadingProvider: NextPage = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const value = { state, dispatch };
  return <Provider value={value}>{children}</Provider>;
};

export function useLoading() {
  const context = React.useContext(LoadingContext);         // error is somewhere here
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useCount must be used within a CountProvider");
  }
  return context;
}

export default LoadingProvider;
```

Loder.tsx

```
const Loader: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.loader_wrapper}>
      <div className={styles.content}>
        <span className={styles.loading_text}>Loading...</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Loader;
```

Index.tsx

```
import Loader from "../components/Loader/Loader";
import { useLoading } from "../context/LoadingContext";
import { useRouter } from "next/dist/client/router";

const { state, dispatch } = useLoading();

const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
  router.events.on("routeChangeStart", () => {
    dispatch({ type: "startLoading" });
  });

  return () => {
    router.events.off("routeChangeStart", () => {
      dispatch({ type: "endLoading" });
    });
  };
}, [dispatch, router]);

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch({ type: "endLoading" });
}, [dispatch, router]);

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {state.loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <>
          <div>
           // other components
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

I got this error. **Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component**

What are the mistakes in my code?

Comment: Well, you currently use multiple hooks outside of the body of a function component. `useRouter`, `useLoading`, `useEffect`

Answer (score 1):

Your index page is calling `useLoading`, `useEffect` and `useRouter` outside the `Home` component.

Refer react [documentation](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html). It clearly mentions the issue you're facing.

> Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.

It should be something like this.

```js
import Loader from "../components/Loader/Loader";
import { useLoading } from "../context/LoadingContext";
import { useRouter } from "next/dist/client/router";

const Home: NextPage = () => {

  const { state, dispatch } = useLoading();

  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    router.events.on("routeChangeStart", () => {
      dispatch({ type: "startLoading" });
    });

    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeStart", () => {
        dispatch({ type: "endLoading" });
      });
    };
  }, [dispatch, router]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "endLoading" });
  }, [dispatch, router]);

  return (
    <>
      {state.loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <>
          <div>
           // other components
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you. But again I got `Server Error
Error: useCount must be used within a CountProvider` this error. DO you know Why?

Comment: You can use Context only within the provider. So the component where you're using `useCount` should be the children of the Provider from that context.